# How do i show that λe^-λx is a valid p.d.f. i.e integrates to 1? Using integration by parts Assuming both Lambda and x > 0.

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand how to show this using u substitution, however attempting to do this using integration by parts gives me u = , du = 0, dv = e^-λx 
v = ? (I'm not sure how you integrate that function. Can someone show me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That integrand is too simple to usefully integrate by parts.  You could do $u=e^{-\lambda x}, du=-\frac 1\lambda e^{-\lambda x}, dv=dx,v=x$, but that gets you to $\int xe^{-\lambda x}dx$ which is a step in the wrong direction.  Usually you want to differentiate the term with $x$ in it to get a lower power, but you don't have one.

Comment: Ah, thank you! So would u substitution be the way to evaluate this?

Comment: Definitely, unless you can integrate $e^{ax}$ without bothering with the substitution.  You might just know that integrates to $\frac 1ae^{ax}$